# iPhone Mail not showing multiple attachments

Tags: iphone, email, attachments

I'm trying to send out an e-mail from a PHP script. The script works fine.

The e-mail shows up in Gmail as HTML, with an (attached) embedded image, and a small (< 1M) downloadable file attached as well. However, the **iPhone doesn't show the second attachment**. If I remove the image, the attachment shows up.

Is the iPhone capable of receiving more than one attachment at a time? Trying to find a solution didn't work as almost all results are for attaching images *on* the iPhone and not *to* it.

Comment: I have received several times email with multiple attachements in it. What kind of file is your second attachement ? Be careful, when you link an image to an email on the iPhone, it shows up directly on the mail, so sometimes you have to go to the bottom of the mail to see others attachements.

Comment: .jpg and .mp4. Embedding the .jpg makes the .mp4 not show up on an iPhone, though both appear and work fine in Gmail.

Comment: To isolate the problem : does it work if you try to send manually a mail with the two attachements on a iPhone ? What happensn if you forward the mail from your iPhone to another mail ?